# Unrar local files to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, rar

I have two Linux servers, one which has several RAR files and another empty one. I would like to extract the archives and move the content to Server 2.

The problem is: I do not have enough storage to extract the files at Server 1. Also I cannot use SSHFS, as no FUSE modules can be loaded on Server 1.

I have seen that `unrar` has the `p` option which sends the output to STDOUT. Is it somehow possible to use this to solve the problem?

Comment: Why don't you copy rar files to remote server then extract?

Comment: I don't have enough storage for both the files and the archives on the other server either.

Comment: Can you use NFS to mount server 2's storage on server 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

`unrar p -inul archive.rar` will print the content of extracted archive on the screen, but it will concatenate all files:

```
$ unrar p -inul archive.rar
content of first
file
and here is second fle
```

So if you have one file in archive, then you could do this:

```
$ unrar p -inul archive.rar | ssh serverb 'cat > file.from.archive'
```

If you have many files, then you could play with:

```
size_of_first_file=$(unrar l archive.rar| head -9| tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
size_of_second_file=$(unrar l archive.rar| head -10| tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Or put it in the loop. and extract files using `dd` instead of `cat`:

```
$ unrar p -inul archive.rar | ssh serverb 'dd of=first_file.from.archive bs=1 count=$size_of_first_file'
```

--- edit ---

My POC:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 user@ssh_server rar_file remote_directory"
  exit 1
fi

i=8
size=0
skip=0
ssh_server=$1
rar_file=$2
remote_directory=$3

until [ "${size}" == "---------" ]
do
  let i=${i}+1
  size=$(unrar l ${rar_file} | head -${i} | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
  filename=$(unrar l ${rar_file} | head -${i} | tail -1 | cut -c 40- )
  directory=$(echo ${filename} | sed -e 's,/[^/]\+,,')
  if [ ${size} == "---------" ]
  then
    break
  else
    echo -e "[*] Extracting: ${filename} size: ${size} from: ${rar_file}"
    unrar p -inul ${rar_file} | ssh ${ssh_server} "
      cd ${remote_directory}
      if [ ! -d ${directory} ]
      then
        mkdir -p ${directory}
      fi
      dd skip=${skip} bs=1 count=${size} of=${filename} 2> /dev/null"
    let skip=${skip}+${size}
  fi
done
```